How to move CefSharp runtime to subfolder during build?
I am using CefSharp.WinForms.NETCore (124.3.80) in a WinForms project.
If I put the PlatformTarget to AnyCPU, CefSharp's runtimes get created in subdirectories:
└───runtimes
    ├───linux-arm64
    │   └───native
    ├───linux-musl-x64
    │   └───native
    ├───linux-x64
    │   └───native
    ├───osx-arm64
    │   └───native
    ├───osx-x64
    │   └───native
    ├───win-arm64
    │   ├───lib
    │   │   └───netcoreapp3.1
    │   └───native
    │       └───locales
    ├───win-x64
    │   ├───lib
    │   │   └───netcoreapp3.1
    │   └───native
    │       └───locales
    └───win-x86
        ├───lib
        │   └───netcoreapp3.1
        └───native
            └───locales

But when I use x64 all the files of the x64 runtime get copied directly into the (root) build dirctory.
To be more precise, this is what makes it behave like that:
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>

Because the project (WinForms) is using
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows7.0</TargetFramework>

only the win-x64 part would be enough.
When putting the files for the browser runtimes in a separate subdirectory (manually), there are various ways to load them just fine.
When using a custom built step and just moving them after the built, it also works fine. But this is very cumbersome, since all the files have to be explicitly addressed and fail-prone if a file is missing or gets added in the future.
Ideally, there would be a way to use the exact same runtime that came with the (nuget) packet and just tell it to go in the appropriate subfolder.
But I can't find it :-)
Before, there was an easy way: <CefSharpTargetDir>
But since .net core version, this is no longer available.
Any help/hint much appreciated and whatever leads me to a solutions will be marked as such. Promise!
EDIT: This doesn't seem to be supported anymore and I couldn't find a working example.
